# Create a list of consequential alphanumeric elements

Tags: python, string, list

I have

```
char=str('DOTR')
```

and

```
a=range(0,18)
```

How could I combine them to create a list with:

```
mylist=['DOTR00','DOTR01',...,'DOTR17']
```

If I combine them in a for loop then I lose the leading zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use list comprehension and format:

```
mylist = ['DOTR%02d'%i for i in range(18)]
```

Or given that `char` and `a` are variable:

```
mylist = ['%s%02d'%(char,i) for i in a]
```

You can, as @juanpa.arrivillaga also specify it as:

```
mylist = ['{}{:02d}'.format(char,i) for i in a]
```

List comprehension is a concept where you write an expression:

```
[<expr> for <var> in <iterable>]
```

Python iterates over the `<iterable>` and unifies it with `<var>` (here `i`), next it calls the `<expr>` and the result is appended to the list until the `<iterable>` is exhausted.

Comment: I would advise people to use `format` specifiers with `"DOTR{:02d}".format(i)`

Answer (score 2):

Use `zfill`:

```
>>> string = "DOTR"
>>> for i in range(0, 18):
...     print("DOTR{}".format(str(i).zfill(2)))
...
DOTR00
DOTR01
DOTR02
DOTR03
DOTR04
DOTR05
DOTR06
DOTR07
DOTR08
DOTR09
DOTR10
DOTR11
DOTR12
DOTR13
DOTR14
DOTR15
DOTR16
DOTR17
>>>
```

And if you want a list:

```
>>> my_list = ["DOTR{}".format(str(i).zfill(2)) for i in range(18)]
>>> my_list
['DOTR00', 'DOTR01', 'DOTR02', 'DOTR03', 'DOTR04', 'DOTR05', 'DOTR06', 'DOTR07', 'DOTR08', 'DOTR09', 'DOTR10', 'DOTR11', 'DOTR12', 'DOTR13', 'DOTR14', 'DOTR15', 'DOTR16', 'DOTR17']
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a list comprehension like so:

```
>>> mylist = [char+'{0:02}'.format(i) for i in a]
>>> mylist
['DOTR00', 'DOTR01', 'DOTR02', 'DOTR03', 'DOTR04', 'DOTR05', 'DOTR06', 'DOTR07', 'DOTR08', 'DOTR09', 'DOTR10', 'DOTR11', 'DOTR12', 'DOTR13', 'DOTR14', 'DOTR15', 'DOTR16', 'DOTR17']
```

Answer (score 1):

can do like this

```
char = str('DOTR')
a=range(0,18)
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append(char + str(i).zfill(2))
print(b)
```

Comment: This doesn't keep the leading zeros, which is a requirement in the OP